# Can you rotate or otherwise change your viewpoint in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

The title says it all. Stuff's in my way. I can't see. Can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Diablo history is the main reason why.

Jay Wilson explains in at http://gamingbolt.com/diablo-iii-game-director-isometric-perspective-vital-for-the-game-and-wont-change.

Comment: can you provide a source?

Comment: Yeah, added it in now.

Answer (score 16):

You cannot rotate the view but you *can* change it a little bit by pressing the <kbd>Z</kbd> key (or whatever you bound to *Toggle Zoom*).

Comment: good point, i'll vote up tomorrow, reached my max today