# How can I zoom in on my character?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you rotate or otherwise change your viewpoint in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66323/can-you-rotate-or-otherwise-change-your-viewpoint-in-diablo-3)

I like looking at my character details, or the world around me, and was surprised that I couldn't zoom in with the mouse wheel.

Is there a way to zoom in on my character?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question is asking if you can rotate your viewport because something is in the way, and this one is asking about zooming in. I actually asked it because I discovered the `[Z]` key yesterday, and think there are many people who would find this answer useful.

Comment: "Or otherwise change". The question is inclusive, and one of the two answers includes the zooming question. It's a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To zoom in, you can hit the <kbd>Z</kbd> button

There is also an option in your settings under Gameplay that will automatically zoom in on your character when you open the inventory screen.

Comment: I knew about the inventory option; I didn't know about the hotkey.  Too bad there's no other options beyond the preset zoom, though.